# expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'struct'

Tags: c, struct

Why I can't place `struct student s;` in that place?

This is the wrong code

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    float mark;

}struct student s;

int main()
{
    scanf("%d%s%f",&s.num,s.name,&s.mark);
    struct student *ptr=&s;
    printf("%d\n",s.num);
    printf("%d\n",ptr->num);
    printf("%d",(*ptr).num);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code without error

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct student
{
    int num;
    char name[20];
    float mark;

}


int main()
{
    struct student s;
    scanf("%d%s%f",&s.num,s.name,&s.mark);
    struct student *ptr=&s;
    printf("%d\n",s.num);
    printf("%d\n",ptr->num);
    printf("%d",(*ptr).num);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to learn struct in c language, I stuck with this. I can uderstand what is the wrong in this code.I am just biginner to programming. Help me to find it

Comment: remove `struct student` before the `struct student s`

Comment: welcome to SO, reading this will explain the correct format  - https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/  -- `struct foo_struct {  } var1, var2, var3;` as one statement, OR as 2 separate with ";" ending the first one - `struct foo_struct {  };`  <== ";" then on a new line  `struct foo_stuct var1, var2, var3;`

Comment: It's a syntax error.  Your options are `s;` or `; struct student s;`.  Avoid global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C expects an optional identifier (variable name).  You have two options:

1. Specify an identifier:

   ```
   struct student
   {
       int num;
       char name[20];
       float mark; 
   } s;
   ```
2. Leave out the identifier and define the variable separately:

   ```
   struct student
   {
       int num;
       char name[20];
       float mark; 
   };

   struct student s;
   ```

Prefer local to global variables.  In your 2nd code example `struct s` is a local variable you are just missing a `;` after the `struct s` definition.

Prefer local to global scope.  If you only need `struct s` in `main()` declare it within that function.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Agree.  Databases is the worst possible example with the whole db being a cluster global variable.  The cool kids call it a "data lake" so it's ok :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 Good idea.  Revised.